# JQuery manipulate div width on iPad / iPhone

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, ipad

I have a number of divs that change from 0 to a variable width. 
This doesn't work on iPad/iPhone; the divs just stay at 0

**Get Html:**

```
var items = {
              item1:22,
              item2:55,
              item3:88,
              item4:36
             };

  for (var key in items ){
      $('.bars').append("<li><div data-percentage='"+items[key]+"' data-title='"+key+"' class='bar'></div></li>"); 
  };
```

**Display**

```
function animate(){
   $(".bars .bar").delay(1000).each(function(i){
      var percentage = $(this).data('percentage');

      $(this).delay(i+"00").animate({'width': percentage + '%'}, 700);

   });
}
```

I've tired changing from animate to width & css but doesn't work.

1. Why does this only seem to happen on Apple devices?
2. Any solutions?

Thank you

Comment: What is the value of `percentage`?

Comment: When is `animate` called (*your* animate)? How is the percentage data attribute assigned a value? And what is the value?

Comment: sorry - animate() is called after the html has been made & appended:

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Problem was with the CSS nothing to do with the Jquery animate